# How to rename files with arabic filenames - Illegal byte Sequence Error

Tags: php, file, renaming

I know there are similar questions about this topic, but unfortunately none have solved my problem

I simply want to rename a file that has an Arabic filename

For example a file named  'ملف.txt' definetly existing in the same folder I have my script in

> rename('ملف.txt','File.txt');

This Gives: 
rename(ملف.txt,File.txt) [function.rename]: No such file or directory

After some googling I learned that I must use:

> $temp = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', 'ملف.txt');
>
> > rename($temp,'File.txt');

This Gives:

rename(,File.txt) [function.rename]: Illegal byte sequence

I also tried using urlencode but that gave:

rename(%D9%85%D9%84%D9%81.txt,File.txt) [function.rename]: No such file or directory

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Answer may largely depend on OS. Can you update question with that information?

Comment: Hey @PLB thanks for ur time, Im on Windows using local xamp server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243863/php-rename-faled-for-filename-with-utf-8-arabic-charset-string

Comment: Yes I read that one @AndrejBestuzhev but I didn't quite understand what he did, he talks about changing something in his code, but I don't have any code just this simple command, I did try basename() though didn't work either

Comment: Did you paste filename in your code, or you read it into variable before?

Comment: @AndrejBestuzhev I tried both, even from a database, all didn't work

Answer (score 1):

**write this code :**

```
$newName  = iconv("utf-8", "cp1256","السلام عليكم.txt");
rename("file.txt", $newName);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the answer? At first it's hard to tell what is your solution. I believe it's the encoding used? Can you maybe also add your result of running the code sample? Did actually work?

Comment: This method renames a file to a name in Arabic encoding and is valid with the Windows system only

Answer (score 0):

This Sample Should Helps ,I Test Bellow Code And It Works In Windows For Arabic/Persian Names:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "CP1256//IGNORE","گچپژ");
echo rename("1.txt", $newname);
```