# rename file name (persian/farsi/arabic) in php

Tags: php, encoding, rename

i want to rename file in php when file name is persian(farsi/arabic).

file name: 'ش' and i want to rename 'a'

and this code not work:

`rename("ش", "a");`

result:

```
Warning: rename(ش,a): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\xampp_new\htdocs\vira2\test.php on line 5
```

PHP Version 5.6.3 on Xampp on Windows

Comment: check this thread, maybe that can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243863/php-rename-faled-for-filename-with-utf-8-arabic-charset-string

Comment: I checked before. but not work. this answer use by linux bash commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
<?php
  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ar');
  mkdir('ش');
  rename('ش', 'a');
```

Comment: this result: rename(%D8%B4,a): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

Comment: Edited again, tested on a mac.

Comment: On Windows 8.1: Warning: rename(ش,a): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in

Comment: Is this the response after `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ar');`? Make sure `urlencode` is removed too.

Comment: Add a `mkdir('ش');` in between and see what happens.

Comment: yes i do it and not work again. perhaps my windows or php config is wrong. because i cant rename, copy and shell_exec when use farsi character in php

Comment: when touch or mkdir is work! but when file is available, Not Work!

Comment: Seems to me that the filenames are encoded in something different

Comment: when touch file by 'ش' name and not rename, this touch file name is Ø´ on windows

Comment: What's your system locale? Run in cmd: `$ systeminfo` and look for `System Locale:`

Comment: en-us;English (United States)

Comment: try `setlocale(LC_ALL, "nb_NO.utf8");` instead

Comment: This is kinda sad, I would say in reality you won't really be running PHP in an windows environment. I suggest running a unix in a virtual machine and sync the files. Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the path of the file.

```
<?php
```

rename("c\ش", "c\a");
?>

Comment: write double backslashes

Comment: Warning: rename(C:\xampp_new\htdocs\test\ش,C:\xampp_new\htdocs\test\a): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)